# what does ((ManifestItem*)manifest->currentItem())->fileContent = currentHtml(); mean in cpp?

Tags: c++

I know this `(*x).y` is like `x->y` in c++, but this code is wired for me. can anybody help me Or give me a reference about it?

Comment: To make things clearer, please put your actual question in the text of the question, not just the title. Also, what do you mean by "code is wired for me" -- was it a typo for "weird"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, using the terms in the variable names, it stores the return-value of the `currentHtml()` function into the `manifest`'s `currentItem`'s `fileContent` variable.

To break it down:

```
((ManifestItem*)manifest->currentItem())
```

There is a method, `currentItem()` in your `manifest` class that will return the, well, "current item". The `(ManifestItem*)` will cast this returned item to a `ManifestItem` data type.

The rest is, I hope, self-explanatory:

```
->fileContent = currentHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((ManifestItem*)manifest->currentItem())->fileContent = currentHtml();
```

1) Call currentHtml()

2) Cast manifest to a pointer to ManifestItem

3) Dereference the pointer in #2 and call its currentItem member function

4) Dereference #3 and assign to its fileContent data member the value from #1 -- or otherwise use operator=()

Answer (score 0):

> what does `((ManifestItem*)manifest->currentItem())->fileContent = currentHtml();` mean in cpp?

It means someone is doing something bad.

First off, you are doing something bad by putting your question in the title. Secondly, that cast is a sign of something suspect. But ...

The first thing you need to know are the C++ operator precedence rules. The element selection operator `->` has precedence over the cast operator `(type)`, so that means we can rewrite this as

```
((ManifestItem*)(manifest->currentItem()))->fileContent = currentHtml();
```

Breaking it down by parts,

1. The `manifest` object's `currentItem()` member function is called, which presumably returns a pointer of some type. Given the cast, I suspect `currentItem()` returns a `void*` pointer.
2. The C-style cast operator converts that pointer to a pointer to a `ManifestItem` object.
3. The `fileContent` member of that object is set to the result of calling `currentHtml()`.